# QT: ASSERT: "uint(i) < uint(size())" in file C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qstring.h, line 1029

Tags: c++, qt, file, qt-creator

I have a file of 10 rows, I want to do a specific thing that is not important in this context. After reaching the end of a line, the program crash with the error in the title.

I went in the line of the header file it's referring:

```
{ Q_ASSERT(uint(i) < uint(size())); return QChar(d->data()[i]); }
```

but still I don't understand. This is my block of code:

```
  QFile file("file.txt");
  QTextStream in(&file);
  QString s;
  int i = 0;
  while(!in.readLine().at(i).isNull()) {
           s = s + in.readLine().at(i);
           ++i;
       }
```

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is copy in the QString variable "s" a line of a file character by character.

Comment: Why do you want to do it character by character?  I mean readline() reads a QString already for you. To copy it you can use operator=(). `s = in.readLine();` would be all that you need to read the first line into `s`

Comment: If you want the length of the line `in.readLine().size()` should give you the # of characters of the next line in the file.

Comment: I do character by character because I want to copy into the QString after a certain character occured.

Comment: For example, here is my line: "Test123 test". What I did before the code i posted here, is cycle until the blank character. Now I want to copy what is after ("test").

Comment: You probably want QString::indexOf() and QString::right() instead of what you are trying. [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf-1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf-1) and [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right)

Comment: Wow, it seem that right method is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `i` is not a valid index for whatever is being returned from `readLine()`. In other words `i` is bigger than the length of the line.

The logic in the loop is really curious. I'm sure it's not doing what you think it's doing.

I *think* what you are trying to write is something like this

```
QFile file("file.txt");
QTextStream in(&file);
QString s;
QString line = in.readLine();
int i = 0;
while (!line.at(i).isNull()) {
       s = s + line.at(i);
       ++i;
}
```

That code just reads one line, your code reads multiple lines.

Comment: How can be if the condition says: "cycle until the end of the line"?

Comment: @Branda The condition doesn't say that at all. For a start the condition itself reads a line, and then the body reads another line. You're looping through the file, not looping through a line.

Comment: Why not? while(!in.readLine().at(i).isNull()) to me stands to: cycle until you reach '\0' character.

Comment: I believe the code in the question keeps reading lines until a null character is in the ith position of a line. However if the line has less than `i` characters it goes out of bounds and at() should throw an exception. It's not iterating over a single line.

Comment: @Branda See edit to the question. You are forgetting that `readLine` has side effects (i.e. it always reads the next line in the file).

Comment: No, I don't think I loop through the file because if I print a character it doesn't print for the number of rows, but in the numbers of character in the line (I'm not a native speaker, I hope it's clear what i meant)

Comment: @Branda I think you are looping through the file, because that's what `readLine` does, it reads lines and if you call it multiple times it will read multiple lines.

Comment: @Branda You could always just try my code and see if it works for you.

Comment: It wasn't my intection offend anybody, I'm sorry. In other case your code still doesn't work, same error occurs.

Comment: @Branda Maybe you should tell us in the question what you think the code should do. To me the code is unusual. I never write code like this with Qt, and I write Qt code for 12+  years now at work.. I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If my version is failing then I think the likeliest explanation is that your QString does not contain any null characters. But I'm not familar with QString.

Comment: I added what I meant to do in the original post.

Comment: Are you expecting your string to contain a null character?

Comment: @john I exept my QString s to not contain the null character. In fact I want my condition to not cycle anymore when the null character occurred. I don't know if that's correct, for null character I meant, in my mind, the end of the line. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't think that a QString uses a null character to indicate the end of the string (or line). But I'm not certain of that. But in any case if you want to copy the whole line to a string the way to do that is one line of code `QString s = in.readLine();` You don't need to write a loop.

Comment: What it bother me is that, after reaching the end of the line (and it reaches), the program stop working. It's not because the method isNull(), because now I tested the method isLetterOrNumber() and that's the same..

Comment: @Branda Undoubtedly that problem is another bug. But without seeing the code I can't say what your misunderstanding is.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues (unless I misunderstand how at() and readLine() work):

1) In the `while()` statement you are reading in a line with `...in.readLine()...`, but then in the loop you read in again with another `...in.readLine()...`. So at the start of the first iteration you read in a line, and then as the body of the loop executes you read in a line again.

2) For every iteration of `while` you are incrementing `i` and grabbing that character from `in`. So for the first iteration (`i=0`) you grab the 0th character, for the second (`i=1`) you grab the 1st character.... and so on.

Comment: The fact is that I tested the body of the cycle to see what it actually do, but as I print the length of the QString s, it printed the number of characters in the line. The problem occured at the end of the line, because I don't actually know..